# How to insert current date and time in a database using SQL?

Tags: java, sql

I used the following code, but the DateTime field in SQL is represented as:

```
2005-04-08 00:00:00
```

I want to have the time too. what should I change?

Here is my code below:

```
// Get the system date and time.
java.util.Date utilDate = new Date();
// Convert it to java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
...
...
...
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, date);
```

Comment: On Microsoft SQL-Server the easiest way to insert current dates to datatables is to add a Default Value to DateTime (or SmallDateTime) field: getdate()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using **setTimestamp** instead of **setDate**, since a timestamp is the prefered format for data *and* time.

Comment: java.sql.Date only supports the date, not time.

From the javadoc - "To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated."

Answer (score 6):

you can set Timestamp import java.sql.Timestamp;

```
stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

instead of

```
stmt.setDate(1, date);
```

o/p will be: 2014-05-16 08:34:52.977

set your DB --column as Timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother retrieving the current time in Java, just let the database do the job:

```
String sql = "insert into some_table (some_column, timestamp_column) values (?, current_timestamp)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, 42);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(time) " +
"VALUES ('" + new java.sql.Date(System.CurrentTimeMillis())"');");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sql function now().

```
INSERT INTO table date_field VALUES(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setDate(utilDate) instead of trying to set SQL date.
In SQL, date and time are different data types.

Answer (score 0):

I did as follows:

```
con = new BDConesion(); //Conexion with de DB
Connection cn = con.conexion()
PreparedStatement st = null;
st = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE (Id,Fecha,contendido) VALUES(?,?,?)");
st.setString(1,String.valueOf(key)); //convert the int to string
st.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
st.setString(3,Cont);//Cont it is a varible string
st.executeUpdate();
```

I hope you serve

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the date in database is a string like "yyyy-mm-dd".

Why not to try:

`String date = "2010-07-28";`

stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(time) " + s);

It's just for the date which you want.

If you want insert now, use the command like:

INSERT INTO mytable(now());